# How can I add two different dataframes element by element in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to add two dataframes that have the same schemas and row numbers in pyspark. I would like to add element by element from `Dataframe1` to `Dataframe2`. In R I can do:

`DataframeSum = Dataframe1 + Dataframe2`

Is there a way to do this in pyspark?

Comment: Spark dataframes are unordered. Even if the row numbers are the same, you don't know which row corresponds to which unless you have an index. If you do, join the dataframes using the index and then add them up.

Comment: @mck , would this mean that since they have the same schemas, I would need to rename the columns of one of the dataframes? Change column names in a dataframe --> join Dataframe1 and Dataframe2 --> sum pairwise?

Comment: yes, that's a possible way

Comment: Thanks, @mck! I didn't quite expect it to be so "painful", as compared to R to pandas :)

Comment: spark is not pandas ;) you have to get used to the lack of an "index" column